# When dragging the Slick Carousel outside of the frame, it renders the slider unclickable

Tags: slick.js

I'm having a problem with Slick Carousel 1.8.1 version (the problem is present also in all previous versions), so the issue is like this on each new slide i have some js animations on click, so i trigger a function to click some elements within that new slide, and they work just fine with arrows, points, keyboard slide, auto slide, but with draggable they do behave differently.

So actually for this are two issues, the first one is when dragging in general doesnt allow them to be clicked, the items says that got the click but because somehow that click was prevented and skiped the animations don't play. But i manage to fix that by disabling pointer events after the slide changes and after the new slide aniamtion is end. But now another problem occoured when I try to drag the slide, and get outside of that frame or window for larger screens the events get blcoked somehow and animations don't work.

- Different Versions of Slick
- Different Versions of jQuery
- Adding a absolute box so that clicks
- Blocking the events while clicking the animation but doesn't work when the cursor is otuside the slider